# getting csv data into highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Re-asking my question in a more understanding manner..

I would like my yAxis to contain soldier names. My xAxis to contain dates. The soldiers name are all in my csv. Each row of soldier name has an extensive list of start and stop dates. This was dumped from an excel table. If soldier_A has 16 dates on his row in CVS, he should have 8 events on his row in the chart. If has 4, should have 2, etc, etc. I have been scouring the net for examples and howto's, but everything I try ends in failure and I could use some help. Thanks.

I found this code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dassey/M3DsP/)

I need to pull from a CSV file. Basically, anyone know how to do that with the example code above? Here is my CSV, partial:

```
Soldier_A,2/28/2014,3/3/2014,1/10/2014,1/12/2014,4/4/2014,4/7/2014,1/24/2014,2/6/2014,2/8/2014,2/9/2014,3/7/2014,3/9/2014,6/18/2014,6/27/2014,5/2/2014,5/4/2014,6/21/2014,6/22/2014,7/9/2014,7/9/2014,7/12/2014,8/1/2014,8/2/2014,8/3/2014,9/6/2014,9/10/2014,9/20/2014,9/21/2014,11/1/2013,11/5/2013,11/7/2013,11/10/2013,12/7/2013,12/14/2013
Soldier_B,1/10/2014,1/12/2014,1/13/2014,1/17/2014,1/27/2014,1/31/2014,2/6/2014,2/9/2014,2/10/2014,2/14/2014,2/21/2014,2/23/2014,2/27/2014,3/2/2014,3/7/2014,3/9/2014,3/11/2014,3/11/2014,3/14/2014,3/16/2014,4/1/2014,4/6/2014,4/8/2014,4/8/2014,4/29/2014,5/4/2014,5/13/2014,5/13/2014,6/16/2014,6/22/2014,7/8/2014,7/8/2014,7/14/2014,7/21/2014,8/12/2014,8/12/2014,9/12/2014,9/12/2014,9/6/2014,9/7/2014,1/14/2013,1/14/2013,10/6/2013,10/6/2013,10/7/2013,10/7/2013,10/8/2013,10/8/2013,11/1/2013,11/6/2013,11/15/2013,11/17/2013,12/6/2013,12/8/2013,12/10/2013,12/10/2013
Soldier_C,10/9/2013,10/15/2013,10/22/2013,10/26/2013,11/3/2013,11/5/2013,11/13/2013,11/19/2013,12/6/2013,12/8/2013,12/15/2013,12/20/2013
Soldier_D,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/31/2013,11/6/2013
Soldier_E,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/24/2013,10/28/2013,10/31/2013,11/6/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,12/5/2013,12/9/2013
Soldier_F,10/6/2013,10/7/2013,10/8/2013,10/8/2013
Soldier_G,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/17/2013,10/21/2013,10/31/2013,11/6/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,12/9/2013,12/13/2013
Soldier_H,1/3/2013,1/6/2013,1/3/2013,1/6/2013,1/3/2013,1/6/2013,1/10/2013,1/13/2013,1/10/2013,1/13/2013,1/10/2013,1/13/2013,1/23/2013,1/27/2013,1/23/2013,1/27/2013,1/30/2013,2/2/2013,1/30/2013,2/2/2013,2/6/2013,2/9/2013,2/20/2013,2/24/2013,2/27/2013,3/3/2013,2/27/2013,3/3/2013,3/13/2013,3/17/2013,3/13/2013,3/17/2013,4/10/2013,4/14/2013,5/15/2013,5/19/2013,8/2/2013,8/22/2013,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/17/2013,10/20/2013,10/24/2013,10/28/2013,11/1/2013,11/4/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,11/22/2013,11/25/2013,12/5/2013,12/8/2013,12/5/2013,12/8/2013,12/5/2013,12/9/2013,12/5/2013,12/9/2013,12/10/2013,12/13/2013
Soldier_I,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/31/2013,11/4/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,12/5/2013,12/9/2013
Soldier_J,1/4/2013,1/5/2013,1/9/2013,1/13/2013,1/21/2013,1/21/2013,1/23/2013,1/23/2013,2/5/2013,2/10/2013,2/6/2013,2/10/2013,2/8/2013,2/9/2013,2/18/2013,2/18/2013,2/20/2013,2/20/2013,2/28/2013,3/2/2013,2/28/2013,3/2/2013,3/18/2013,3/18/2013,3/20/2013,3/20/2013,4/2/2013,4/6/2013,4/11/2013,4/13/2013,4/22/2013,4/22/2013,4/22/2013,4/28/2013,4/24/2013,4/24/2013,5/1/2013,5/5/2013,5/2/2013,5/4/2013,5/20/2013,5/20/2013,5/22/2013,5/22/2013,6/4/2014,6/13/2014,6/4/2014,6/13/2014,6/14/2014,6/19/2014,6/14/2014,6/19/2014,7/8/2013,7/14/2013,7/14/2013,7/19/2013,7/14/2013,7/21/2013,7/22/2013,7/22/2013,7/24/2013,7/24/2013,8/1/2013,8/10/2013,8/19/2013,8/19/2013,8/21/2013,8/21/2013,9/23/2013,9/23/2013,9/24/2013,9/24/2013,10/5/2013,10/6/2013,10/16/2013,10/21/2013,10/22/2013,10/22/2013,10/24/2013,10/24/2013,10/30/2013,11/4/2013,11/19/2013,11/19/2013,11/21/2013,11/21/2013,12/17/2013,12/17/2013,12/19/2013,12/19/2013
Soldier_K,1/14/2013,1/14/2013,1/10/2014,1/12/2014,1/13/2014,1/17/2014,1/27/2014,1/31/2014,2/6/2014,2/9/2014,2/10/2014,2/14/2014,2/21/2014,2/23/2014,2/27/2014,3/2/2014,3/7/2014,3/9/2014,3/11/2014,3/11/2014,3/14/2014,3/16/2014,4/1/2014,4/6/2014,4/8/2014,4/8/2014,4/29/2014,5/4/2014,5/13/2014,5/13/2014,6/16/2014,6/22/2014,7/8/2014,7/8/2014,7/14/2014,7/21/2014,8/12/2014,8/12/2014,9/12/2014,9/12/2014,9/6/2014,9/7/2014,11/2/2013,11/3/2013,11/4/2013,11/6/2013,12/6/2013,12/8/2013,12/10/2013,12/10/2013
Soldier_L,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/17/2013,10/21/2013,10/30/2013,11/4/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts has a CSV importing method. Have you read http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json#1

Comment: Sir, yes sir, I have read that. I can pull data from csv into highcharts. But I do not know how to pull it in similar to my example fiddle. Here is my poor excuse for code:
http://jsfiddle.net/dassey/v2phV/



Perhaps I can reference the lines in some manner that make js treat it as one data block. I have no clue.

Comment: Here is a better example of my total efforts so far: http://jsfiddle.net/dassey/fzurG/10/
<p>
I put it all into the script and just been trying to learn how to manipulate it from there.

Comment: So what is your problem exactly?

Comment: You're not using a CSV file in your example. Also, you're mixing example code you found with your data-set, and they are not compatible. In order to help you, we need to know what you want your chart to represent.

Comment: I really cannot explain it any simpler. yAxis is names. xAxis is dates. You can see the data i am trying to use. http://jsfiddle.net/dassey/HvM8K/ is what I want. But to populate it with my csv. I can make my csv say anything it needs to say.

Comment: I understand you want names yAxis, and the dates to be xAxis, but the fact that you have pairs of dates makes it more complicated. Your last fiddle makes more sense, should these date intervals take on "gantt chart" form?

Comment: Im getting the sense your right. I only put my data in this form because I thought it would be easier. Each date is either a start date or stop date. SO if a row has 4 dates, it should have 2 events. I will look into this. Thanks for sharing your knowledge too, really appreciated